# printjs in angular having properties with json object inside one other json

Tags: angular, printjs

I am using printJs library for printing in properties I added JSON object properties its working fine, but if that JSON object contains one more JSON object inside it is showing `[object object]`. Can anyone tell me the solution?

```
 PrintJS({

  printable: printIndexes,
  properties: ['reporter', 'entryTime', 'exitTime', 'status'],

  type: 'json',
  gridHeaderStyle: 'color: red;  border: 2px solid #3971A5;',
  gridStyle: 'border: 2px solid #3971A5;',
  header: 'List of master index'
```

[image]

Please see this image it is showing like `[object object]` there I want to display name.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell PrintJS which property in the nested object that should be printed. For example:

```
 printJS({
  printable: printIndexes,
  properties: ['reporter.name', 'entryTime', 'exitTime', 'status.value'],
  type: 'json',
  gridHeaderStyle: 'color: red;  border: 2px solid #3971A5;',
  gridStyle: 'border: 2px solid #3971A5;',
  header: 'List of master index'
});
```

Here is an example fiddle printing data from nested objects:

https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/bLq52fyu/

Answer (score 0):

traverse the object inner deep
for example:

```js
user:{
    name:'xxx',
    address:{
              building:{
                           no:64,
                           street:corinder
                        },
              city:'texas'
             }
       }
```

You can traverse by `user.address.building.no` it will shown `64`